# Prevent thread creation in AppDomain

Tags: c#, multithreading, permissions

I've set up a little example where I loaded an assembly into a new AppDomain without any Permission. This works fine, the assembly can't access the file system and can't listen to sockets.

But there is another thing i want to prevent: Thread creation. Why? Cause theoreticly this assembly can create a thread which creates even more threads and flood my memory.

I thought of the (in my opinion) best way: Limiting the memory of an AppDomain. Is this possible? And if not, what can i do to avoid thread creation?

Used this code to create the thread

```
Thread t = new Thread(this.DoWork);
t.Start();
```

And this code for the AppDomain

```
 PermissionSet set = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
 set.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
 set.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read |
                                        FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery, 
                                        this.path));

 AppDomainSetup info = new AppDomainSetup { ApplicationBase = this.path };

 this.domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Sandbox", null, info, set, null);
```

(Ok, i gave access to the file system in the folder where i want to load the assembly, this is just because `StrongName fullTrustAssembly = typeof(SecureInstance).Assembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();` don't work for me either.

Hope s/o can help. (:

Comment: No way you can do this AFAIK :) The only thing you can do is to set the limit of threads in a thread pool

Comment: AFAIK every AppDomain needs to create at least one thread - otherwise it can't run... so disabling thread creation would mean that it can't run at all IMHO. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Elastep Thanks for your answer, but is this secure? I think it's possible to extend the thread limit at any piece of software. The whole thing gives Java a great plus. In Java the SecurityManager is asked before thread creation.

Comment: @Yahia Well, I want to disallow thread creation in a foreigner code. Of course one thread is needed, but it shouldn't be possible to flood my memory by simply creating tons of threads.

Comment: @PhilippSpieß you didn't answer my question... what is it you want to achieve ? Are you trying to build a sandbox ? Are you trying to integrate "foreign/external" code in a way that it can't do any harm ?

Comment: Exactly, I want to integrate foreign code (And yes, I'm totally freaked out). Sorry for not answering your question.

Comment: @PhilippSpieß "flood memory" is always possible... even without thread creation... how much do you "distrust" that external code ? like "might be buggy" or "could be malicous" ?

Comment: The second. :D Well, principle it's about a platform where people can create theire AI for programming challenging games (Something like AntMe). The platform is than creating the binaries and the game (via an API) downloads these binaries and compute the results in 1 on 1 games. The whole thing is running pretty fine in Java now, so I'm trying to extend the range of programming languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there's no easy answer for this. What you can do is use the .NET Profiling API to try and monitor memory usage in your AppDomain. You can find out more about it here, but you'll need to do some digging: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384493.aspx

Anyway, isn't it better to run whatever you want to run in a separate process with a lower priority, so if it goes all wild with memory allocations, it doesn't affect your process, the OS kills it and it doesn't affect your main process?

Comment: The issue with process-level isolation is the overhead of multiple processes.  Since threads can't be aborted safely by a hosting AppDomain, I must make sure they can't be created.  If this can't be done, then I have to perhaps monitor for "violations" and kill the whole process.  Easier but worse for performance is pessimistically kill the process every time.  But that hurts the performance of everybody who's behaving.